# Terminal says 'No such file or directory' when open

Tags: macos, git, bash, terminal

In the last couple of days my terminal has been saying

`-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin: No such file or directory`

However, all of the above do exist. I was playing around with `$PATH` variable last week but the error I am now getting appeared days after I stopped playing with the `$PATH` variable.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the error in my termianl.app]

Here are the contents of my .bash_profile that I was playing about with too:

[image: The contents of my .bash_profile]

Comment: Somewhere you have `$PATH` on a line by itself (or an incorrect assignment like `$PATH = <something>` which is causing the shell to try to run your path as a command. Go look at your shell startup files.

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner could you please expand on how to resolve the issues I am having? I am happy to provide further information / screenshots etc.

Comment: Look at the files you were editing the other day. Do any lines *start* with `$PATH`? If so that's probably the problem line. If not you get to look for other places where you used `$PATH` incorrectly. There likely aren't a lot.

Comment: The error message may indicate that you are trying to _execute_ $PATH So as suggested by  Etan Reisner try to find your error that might look like: `$($PATH)` or `. $PATH`

Comment: @EtanReisner I cannot delete these lines I think as I need them for developing, or is that not the case?

Comment: @prodev_paris When you say 'find the errors' what error do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Alan errors as specified in my comment... Maybe a `grep -Hn PATH *.sh` can help you find the incriminated file!

Comment: @Alan guessing your edited files where in your home try: `grep -Hn PATH ~/*.sh` Anyway NEVER execute a command if you don't know what it do! Please read [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) documentation.

Comment: @prodev_paris Thanks, I now get `grep: /Users/alan/*.sh: No such file or directory` I am sorry for the repeated comments, would you like to move to an discussion room?

Comment: If you just added those two `export` lines then those aren't the problem. If you also added a `$PATH` line then that is the problem. `grep -Hn $HOME/.bash*` is more likely to be useful to find the file/line in question but even that may not find it.

Comment: @EtanReisner When I ran `grep -Hn PATH ~/*.sh` which was suggested by @prodev_paris I got the message `grep: /Users/alan/*.sh: No such file or directory`. When I run the line you suggested: `grep -Hn $HOME/.bash*` I get nothing

Comment: @prodev_paris What would you suggest I do next after getting the error: `grep: /Users/alan/*.sh: No such file or directory`?

Comment: Bleh, left part of the command out sorry. Try `grep -Hn PATH $HOME/.bash*` The error from the other command is because you don't have any `*.sh` files in your home directory. That was just an incorrect assumption on their part.

Comment: None of those looks likely to be the problem. You could try adding `set -x` to the top of your `.bash_profile` script to see if that helps you find the line that is causing the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78420/discussion-between-alan-and-etan-reisner).

Comment: @EtanReisner When you say " try adding set -x to the top of your .bash_profile script " what exactly and how do I do this. I am not very comfortable / experienced with terminal commands

Comment: @Alan — Looks like this question has been answered, and it involves your `.bash_profile` file. Please paste the file's source (or the relevant parts, anyway) in your question for first-time visitors. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of your `.bash_profile` is the problem.

That line is attempting to run `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin` as a command which causes the error you see when you start the shell.

Remove that line and the error should go away.

Comment: Doesn't this break anything that relies on those paths being in .bash_profile?

Comment: @JWoodchuck No. Because the broken line (the first line) wasn't setting the `PATH` variable. It was running that string as a command (which obviously fails). Also all but `/usr/local/git/bin` in that string should be in `$PATH` by default. If, `/usr/local/git/bin` was needed then it would want to get added to line three (the `PATH=....` line).